# Deleting some data from partition will impact local index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a partitioned table "alarms" as following

- partitioned by range(version); version: 1,2,3 ..
- each partition have local index on version
- each partition have a mix of columns as local indexes
- version is a local index
- no global index

Due to some business constrains,

- I need to delete some data from each version (but not all partition data).
- no update will happen to old versions, only select
- on daily basis, i am inserting new version data

So for this i will delete as following:

```
delete /*+ full(alarms) parallel(alarms,4)*/ from alarms where version <= (number) and alarm_type = 'type1';
```

And this will not delete all the partition. But may be each 1 month, this partition will be empty.

So I have a procedure loops on all versions and all empty partitions will be dropped by name.

My question is: Until partition is not empty

- this may impact performance?
- Do i need to rebuild index each delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This may impact performance?

I'm not sure just how you mean this. If you mean "will deleting data from a table impact other concurrent users of that table", the answer is yes, although it's impossible to state what the degree of impact will be. If you mean, "will deleting data from a table have long-term impact on access to that table", my answer is that there should be very little long-term affect.

2. Do I need to rebuild index each delete?

Deleting data from a table is a normal activity in a database, and the indexes will be maintained properly.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob! for first point, what i meant is dml operations performance specially selecting data from the impacted partition. and in case deleting some other data from the same partition .. and so on. For the second point, your answer is to the point!

Comment: I think also gathering stats for this table may help on daily basis, since a new version (partition) will be created and old partitions may updated/deleted on daily basis

Comment: You should be gathering statistics regularly on any table which has significant changes made to it.